# Link an email to compose in SugarCRM

Tags: email, sugarcrm

I have a custom module with an email field. What I want is in the detail view a link to the email. When I click on it, the compose mail wizard of SugarCRM should open in a pop-up window.

I tried with this code in my custom detailviews.php file:

```
'customCode' => '<a onclick=\'SUGAR.quickCompose.init($j_quickComposeOptions);\'>{$fields.doctorprimaryemailaddress.value}</a>'
```

But this code does not open the Quick Compose window. Do I need to add any more?

Answer (score 2):

If you set the "mail client" setting in the user profile to SugarCRM instead of external this should happen automatically.